# Which format and font size should I take?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I have a dilemma. The design team provides me the company's icons that I should use for the application, but not too sure which one should I use (format and size)

Here is the list:

Icons fonts:

- Sizes: 16x16, 24x24, 32x32
- Formats: .eot, .svg, .ttf, .woff and .woff2

Icons images:

- Sizes: 16x16, 24x24, 32x32
- Types: png and svg

Svg are more flexible, but most of the reading seems to focus on png type.

Also, which sizes should I use for the app bar or the tab bar that will work fine with iOS and Android and for different type of resolutions? I understand it depends of the resolution of the screen, but which size should be 1x, 2x an 3x? Is there a rule of thumbs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flutter handles different screen resolutions automatically. That means when you create a container with a certain size, it will scale up accordingly on higher-density devices (108px on a 2.0x device).

That said, the standard widgets (such as `AppBar` or `CupertinoNavigationBar`) are looking good on all devices..

If you want to roll out your own design, you can always take a look at the [Material spec](https://material.io/) to get some ideas for measurements.

About icons: Flutter needs icons that scale well, and has good support for icon fonts (no official support for svg).

I would recommend you to use [this generator](http://fluttericon.com/) to convert your svg icons to a flutter-compatible icon font.

Comment: Thanks @boformer for your input. So, if I understand right, you won't give any height and width to the app bar action icons even if it comes from outside Icons class? Also, how Flutter can work with my icon fonts and which file type should I use?

Comment: I answered my questions related to the file type. I used .ttf, add it to pubspec, then create a class to access all my icons.

Comment: the default icon size is 24.0, but I think you can change it by wrapping an icon theme around your app.